# Both AD Import and SharePoint 2013 AD Sync (with FIM) fail to import users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, fim, active-directory-import

2 Server Environment:

> SharePoint 2013 On Server 2008 R2
>   SQL 2008 R2

AD is 2 domain servers - primary and secondary - Server 2003 w/ 2003 AD Functional Level

SharePoint User Profile service is configured and I can get the Synchronization service started so I am not "stuck on starting". Also, I have verified with AD tools that I can connect to the AD servers and that All replicate dir permissions are set correctly according to Spence Harbar's setup "Bible" :-)

When I try to run a Full Sync via the SharePoint user profile import (the SP2010 way) I get the following error on the DS_FULLIMPORT step in FIM

> The replication operation encountered a database error  / error code 8451

When I run the AD Import I get the following Error in the SharePoint ULS logs:

> ScanDirSyncChanges: Exception thrown by Dirsync request: page 0, 
>   LdapServer 'xxx.xxx.dom, rootDn 'DC=XXX,DC=dom', 
>   exception 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: 
>   The server cannot handle directory requests.

I can find almost nothing on this anywhere. There was a .Net 2.0 hotfix for the 2nd error but that has been applied in a service pack already.

Help. I have built and rebuilt the User Profile Service multiple time with the same results. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

According to Spence Harbar in his post: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

> If our Domain Controller is running Windows 2003 or earlier functional level we also need to make the DOMAIN\spups account a member of the Pre Windows 2000 Compatible access built in group

Did you do this?

Comment: Yes the User Profile account is in this group

Comment: Did you perform the necessary security changed to the containers in AD?

Comment: Yes. Everything is configured EXACTLY per the Harbar UPS 'bible' :-)

Comment: OK, is it a multiserver environment? Are you configuring the service on the correct server and no other?

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you give,especially Error Code 8451, this error is more related to Active Directory rather SharePoint Sync.

did you check this technet and try to fix this.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/replication-error-8451-the-replication-operation-encountered-a-database-error(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/replication-error-8451-the-replication-operation-encountered-a-database-error%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

or this KB.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2645996

Comment: Yes. I went through both of these posts before I posted my question. The AD server replicates successfully and syncs with a dozen other applications (not SP2013)

Comment: Also, The AD guys ran DCDIAG and all passed so I don't think it is AD. In any case the solutions offered in the above articles are a bit nuclear in that if the syncs are working every where else, why would you rebuild AD for Sharepoint

Comment: what level on AD you give the replicate permission to sync account?

Comment: The User Profile Account was temporarily given Domain Admin rights so that any and all permissions issues would be eliminated. However, the account was set up initially EXACTLY per Spence's article. That is always my go to reference when setting up the UPS.

Comment: did that fix the problem?

Comment: no it didn't fix the issue. Even a call to MS Support AD team hasn't yielded a solution as AD Replication (say from Primary to Secondary DC) is otherwise fine and runs with no errors.